# Is it possible to check the in app purchase while compiling the app or We should check it only after creating a signed apk?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have done inapp purchase in my app.Now i need to perform a test on it also i having my in app id with me when compiling my project and i tried to perform inapp it shows error message like this

```
"This version of the application is not configured for billing through Google Play. Check the help center for more information".
```

Now i need to know how to solve it? and What are the methods to be followed while checking in app purchase?
Need your suggestion friends
Thank you in advance

Here is my fragment?which is not working in lower versions of android

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

public class Fragadmob extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragadmob, container,   false);

        //Admob        
         RelativeLayout gonad=(RelativeLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.adview153613);
         ImageView addviewimage=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.addviewimage);
         ImageView inap=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.addviewimage1);

         //   AdView adView = new AdView(getActivity());
           AdView adView = (AdView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.adView);
          AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
              .build();
          adView.loadAd(adRequest);
         addviewimage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 Intent viewIntent =
                          new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
                            Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=SentientIT+America,+LLC"));
                          startActivity(viewIntent);                

            }

         });
         inap.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),Inapp.class);
                     startActivity(intent);         

                }

             });

          if(addviewimage.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) 
            {            
             addviewimage.getLayoutParams().height = 30;                    
                // code to do for Portrait Mode
            } 
          SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
            boolean isPurchase = preferences.getBoolean("isPurchase",false);
  if(isPurchase){

       gonad.setVisibility(View.GONE); //work 
  }
        return rootView;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to publish an alpha test release with a signed APK to Google play store or you can test also static responses (https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-static)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion fab.I have one more problem see the next coment

Comment: In my app i have included add mob inside the fragment.I have called that fragment in all  other xml files.While running the app i got error But in lollipop it runs good it doesn't show any error.If i remove the fragment it runs in all android versions.This is the problem in my app

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can test the inApp Purchase items in your app, only after signing your apk and upload to Google Play Store.
Therefore add items to playstore as needed.
Then find them in your app sku details, don't publish the apk only test in testing mode of google play store, like alpha testing.

Thanks

for more details:
http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html
http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/list-iab-products.html

Comment: Thank you androider after uploading it to play store i will check it.I have one more problem in my app.see the next comment

Comment: In my app i have included add mob inside the fragment.I have called that fragment in all other xml files.While running the app i got error But in lollipop it runs good it doesn't show any error.If i remove the fragment it runs in all android versions.This is the problem in my app.Tell me the possible way to solve it

Comment: admob is easy to code and works for every version with the same code, checkout your fragment codes

Comment: I have checked my fragment code every thing is fine,But still its not working.I posted my fragment make read on it

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got a clear solution.We can check the in app purchase of our application only after uploading a beta version of our app in the playstore.In beta version we will not be charged for the testing of in-app purchase.